# Make exceptions in the CSS code

Tags: css

I have tried to exclude the Revolution Slider, and two other elements from being padded, while the rest of the site is supposed to be padded, but it doesn't work.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px)

    .nm-page-wrap-inner:not(.wpb_revslider_element):not(.nm-single-product-showcase):not(.wpb_revslider_element) {
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;
    }

    .nm-header-inner  {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;
    } 

    .nm-footer-bar-inner {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;
    }  
    .wpb_text_column .woocommerce-MyAccount-content {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .wpb_revslider_element {
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing an open braket at the firts line. it must be `@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {`

Comment: Hi! I was going to make some elements work around the CSS. The CSS was padding and i wanted to have full screen sliders that also got padding. I found out that the solution was margin:-50px. Consider this solved

Answer (score 0):

I was going to make some elements work around the CSS. The CSS was padding and i wanted to have full screen sliders that also got padding. I found out that the solution was margin:-50px. Consider this solved